# Почему вместо одного запроса отправляется два?

Tags: javascript

Пишу приложение на React, получаю данные с сервера с помощью Fetch. В хроме вот такая картина:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вместо одного запроса, я вижу два, но с разным типом. Запрос с типом fetch выполняется быстро, а с типом json - медленно.

Вопрос - почему два запроса?

Comment: Напишите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который бы давал эти самые два запроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый - это запрос с `Request Method:OPTIONS` в котором есть заголовок с желаемым методом, например: `Access-Control-Request-Method:GET`. Он проверяет, может ли сервер принять get запрос по такому адресу. Ну а потом, в случае, если OPTIONS прошел, то отправляется уже настоящий запрос.

Comment: Т.е. все нормально, так и должно быть, на сколько я понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, так и должно быть. Не за что)

Comment: Для GET-запроса OPTIONS не отправляется. Очень высока вероятность, что вы не правы.

Comment: А при отправке на свой же домен OPTIONS не отправляется вообще никогда, что ещё более повышает вероятность, что вы не правы и дело не в этом.

Comment: Все запросы кросс-доменные.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов GET или не-GET?

Comment: @andreymal отправляю GET.

Comment: Ну при cors для get-запроса options отправляются. [тыц](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @ИльяБизунов тогда возможно этот ответ неверный, но без воспроизводимого примера ничего точно сказать нельзя

Comment: @Mikl OPTIONS отправляются не для любого GET